# Изменение адреса в mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Создал в корне сайта файл .htaccess с содержимым

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase '/'
RewriteRule ^post/([^/\.]+)/?$ post.php?num=$1 [L]
```

т.е. адрес site.loc/post.php?num=3 должен по идее преобразовываться в site.loc/post/3, но этого не происходит. Что я делаю не так? Помогите, пожалуйста, как правильно.

Строку третью откуда-то скопипастил, ибо сам пока не очень понимаю принцип регулярок и работы mod_rewrite'а...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?? с какой стати "адрес site.loc/post.php?num=3 должен по идее преобразовываться в site.loc/post/3" ?? :) Как раз наоборот. Ссылки site.loc/post.php?num=3 на сайте у тебя генерирует САЙТ.

Comment: ничё не понимаю...
а как надо правильно задавать, чтобы строки 
site.loc/post.php?num=3
преобразовывались и выводились в адресной строке как
site.loc/post/3
?
подскажите пожалуйста..

Comment: если ты ВВЕДЕШЬ в адресной строке site.loc/post/3/ то у тебя все будет работать, если ты хочешь, чтобы на САЙТЕ выводились такие ссылки, то тебе надо в искодниках сайта сделать, чтобы САЙТ выводил такие ссылки.

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы сайт выводил такие ссылки?

Comment: переписать весь код сайта, который отвечает за вывод ссылок :)

Comment: не очень понял....можно пример? разве сайт может влиять на именна урлов кроме как get и названиями файлов страниц?

Comment: Кажется вкурил, как всё работает, простите, нуб совсем пока :)
у меня другой вопрос возник:
если я обращаюсь к странице вот так
site.loc/post.php?num=1
то у меня всё отображается корректно,
если же я обращаюсь вот так
site.loc/post/1
то почему-то страница грузится очень странно...по-моему, там не загружается таблица стилей. что в этом случае делать?

Comment: ну как, теперь везде где идет подключение css стилей и выводятся картинки необходимо в начале пути поставить /

например: 
было <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
станет <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 1):

RewriteBase '/' - лишняя строка

Comment: пофиг, не в этом смысл вопроса)