# Почему не работает mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Добрый день! Подскажите, почему правило переадресации не работает (по идее должно срабатывать при profiles.php?id=1 на users/1/:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteRule ^/users/([0-9]+)/ /profiles.php?id=$1
```

*-Файл .htaccess*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не должен, он наоборот работает... читаем тут: [изменение адреса в mod_rewrite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150967/htaccess-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-mod_rewrite).

Comment: Я в принципе разобрался, вроде работает. Но! При переходе `profiles.php?id=1` нас не перекидывает на `users/1/`

Comment: а должен? что работает и как разобрался. нет тут телепатов угадывать...

Comment: @thunder, ну вообще то да, должен редирект быть.

Comment: ? по вышеприведенному коду редиректа С profiles.php НА /users/ не должно быть, как раз наоборот будет., с точки зрения сервера.
пользователь воодит и будет видеть /users/число, а этой записью мы говорим серверу, что пользователь "ввел" /profiles.php?id=число

если хочется, чтобы был именно редирект С profiles.php НА /users/, то это пишется подругому.

Comment: @thunder, а как, не скажешь? Пробивал в конце строки прописать: [L,R=301], не помогает.